# MySQL: Regular Expressions & Wildcards

Tags: mysql, regex, wildcard

In a MYSQL table I have a multiple text entries with the field of

Not Valid After: Dec 02 19:40:51 2016 GMT

What I'm trying to do is use REGEXP to find these entries and ignore anything which is less than Dec 31 23:59:59 2016 GMT. What is the best way to go about this?

Example:   SEARCH_STRING where TABLE_COLUMN REGEXP "Not Valid After: blah blah" is less than Dec 31 23:59:59 2016 GMT.

I know that example is a little lacking in proper syntax, but I'm sure you get the gist of what I'm getting at. How do I take a set date, compare it to what's listed in a specific string buried in the details of larger text, and ignore anything between now() and that preset time being the end of the year?

Comment: So far I've tried REGEXP "Not Valid After:" just to pull up the correct datasets, but what I'm lacking is how to deal with the "Dec 02 19:40:51 2016 GMT" date field on the "Not Valid After" line to ignore everything less than Dec 31 23:59:59 2016 GMT.    Effectively I'm asking for multiple things to be done at once.  First isolate the "Not Valid After" line in the text. Then take the date, which comes after that "Not Valid After" line, and compare it to a predefined date.     Maybe something easier is needed like REGEXP NOT "Not Valid After: * 2016 GMT"  But can you setup a REGEXP wildcard?

Comment: Chris thanks.  Your blurb hit the spot..  "not REGEXP "Not Valid After .* (20([0][0-9]|1[0-6])|1[89][0-9]{2}) GMT"    That's just what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably normalize the DB so the column was just a date, then you could use standard comparison functions (`<=`). Alternatively you could use a regex that will match the 4 year integers. Something like:

```
Not Valid After .* (20([0][0-9]|1[0-6])|1[0-9]{3}) GMT"
```

in mysql it'd be used as:

```
COLUMN not REGEXP "Not Valid After .* (20([0][0-9]|1[0-6])|1[0-9]{3}) GMT"
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b735/4

You'll need to increase the character class, `1[0-6]` as time passes; for next year `1[0-7]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(COLUMN, 'Not Valid After: %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y GMT')) < 2017
```